# Mass dimension of momentum space

Tags: kinematics, momentum, dimensional-analysis

What is the mass dimension of $D$-dimensional momentum space?

$\frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D}$. Does this have mass dimension $D$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because momentum $k$ has mass dimension 1.